# Grails4 url-mappings broken?

Tags: grails

Is the url-mappings-report broken?

```
$ grails -v
| Grails Version: 4.0.0
| JVM Version: 11.0.3
$ grails create-app --profile rest-api UrlMappingsTest
$ cd UrlMappingsTest
$ grails url-mappings-report
| Error Command [url-mappings-report] error: Could not execute build using Gradle distribution 'https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-5.1.1-bin.zip'. (Use --stacktrace to see the full trace)
```

Do you confirm you have the same result (if so, is this a known bug)? Or is there something wrong on my end?

Comment: Doesn't work for me either. Probably best to report it on GitHub.

Comment: This doesn't work for me either.